# Windows phone mango with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, wcf, windows-phone-7

I have a WP7 app idea that requires a connection to a server database (running SQL Server 2008 R2). I checked online and accordingly it is usually done by using WCF that expose the database for the phone to be used.

I would like to know if the new mango update provide anything new to the process I already mentioned. I am aware of the local database, but in my case I need the SQL Server database for the bigger size.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

(Even in mango) there is no way to directly connect to a SQL Server database.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use oData to expose your database on the wire. The oData client library is built into the Mango APIs under [System.Data.Services.Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc490442%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

However, be aware of the requirements of your application and architect approrpriately. There may be a need to provide some sort of caching plan as network connectivity is never guaranteed on a mobile device.